# Unexpected behaviour in Firefox when getter returns a function

Tags: javascript, this, getter, prototype-programming

```
Object.defineProperty(Number.prototype, 'foo', {
  get: function () {
    var me = this
    return function () { return me.valueOf() }
  }
})

console.log(5..foo())
```

This logs 5 in Chrome, but 0 in Firefox.

```
Object.defineProperty(Number.prototype, 'bar', {
  get: function () {
    return this.valueOf()
  }
})

console.log(5..bar)
```

This logs 5 in both browsers as expected.

Can anyone explain this behaviour, and perhaps suggest how the first example could be rewritten to work in Firefox as it does in Chrome?

[jsfiddle.net/V2sHg/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/V2sHg/2/)

Comment: I couldn't figure it out, but maybe Firefox doesn't want to return a function when getting a property.

Comment: Very strange behaviour indeed - Firefox appears to be binding the Number prototype to `this` when it tries to get a function, but removing the `()` after `5..foo` binds it to an instance of `Number` instead.  Perhaps it's a bug?

Answer (score 0):

It works for me on FF when using "new Number(value)" but not using directly a "number":

Try:

```
var n = new Number(8);
n.foo(); --> 8
```